# How do I get Ubuntu 12.10 to recognize a DisplayLink monitor

Tags: 12.10, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 12.10, I have one external monitor connected using the vga port and it works fine. I want to get a second external monitor connected to it via a DisplayLink adapter. When I plug it in the screen turns on a goes green.
But when I run xrandr this is what I get as output

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2650 x 1680, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1600x900+1050+347 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 214mm
   1600x900       60.1*+
   1440x900       59.9  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1050x1680+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      59.9*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     75.0     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I tried to download the display link drivers but they aren't being found. What is my next step here?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the kernel 3.7.1 or the new version 3.9.6 it should work almost plug and play.

I was using Linux Mint 14 with kernel 3.7.1 and now I am using Linux Mint 15 with kernel 3.9.6 without any issues and the need to make extra tweaks. If you need to make some adjustments create a small script and execute it at the start up just like that:

## !/bin/bash

xrandr --newmode "1360x768_60.00" 84.75 1360 1432 1568 1776 768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-0 1360x768_60.00
xrandr --auto --output DVI-0 --mode 1360x768_60.00 --right-of LVDS1

Of course just use the specific requirements for your Displaylink USB resolution.